# SQL: Limit by unknown number of occurences

Tags: sql

Having a SQL table, consistent of the columns id and type. I Want to select only the first occurences of a type without using WHERE, since i dont know which types wild occur first, and without LIMIT since i don't know how many.

```
id | type
---------
1  | 1 
2  | 1 
3  | 2 
4  | 2 
5  | 2
```

E.g.:

> SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY type (+ ?) should only return id 1 and 2
>
> SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY type DESC (+ ?) should only return id 3, 4 and 5

Can this be acheived via standard and simple SQL operators?

Comment: Which database system is it?

Comment: Can you post your expected output as well

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62598/1822

Comment: Currently your `ORDER BY` is pointless, as the rows you seem to be expecting all share the same id (note also that ordering by a constant value isn't guaranteed to get stable result ordering).  Is it that you simply want the highest and lowest `type` value?  Or something else?

Comment: THe DBMS is postgresql. I think I'll do with a nested query using the (min) operator as suggested by Thorsten Kettner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy. You must use a where clause and evaluate the minimum type there.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE type = (select min(type) from mytable) 
ORDER BY id;
```

EDIT: Do the same with max() if you want to get the maximum type records.

EDIT: In case the types are not ascending as in your example, you will have to get the type of the minimum/maximum id instead of getting the minimum/maximum type:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE type = (select type from mytable where id = (select min(id) from mytable)) 
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: the OP wants it `without using WHERE`

Comment: Because he/she doesn't know the value to compare with. My answer is: You don't have to know it beforehand; you can evaluate it in the where clause with min/max.

Comment: This will do is in this case, a nested WHERE is fine. Thanks!